# How do I center text when there is a vertical navbar/sidebar?

Tags: html, css

My website has a vertical navigation bar to the left, so when I center text it is centered but not centered in the green section.

```css
.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    height:100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0px;
    width: 300px;
    background:#6495ED;
}
 
h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
 
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #6495ED;
}
 
li a {
    display: block;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 8px 0 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: "Verdana", Geneva, sans-serif;
}
 
 
li a:hover {
    background-color:#27C0FD;
    color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
<body bgcolor="#81F781">
<head>
<h1> Informational Tech Site</h1>
 
</head>
 
<body>
<div class="sidebar">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>  
</div>
 
</body>
```

Code is here. http://pastebin.com/xgvt4P0a

Here is the image the text is centered, but not centered in the green section. https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MuaC.jpg
Thanks!

Comment: note that, using `padding-left` or anything else is a wrong way to fix this. but it's up to you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specified an absolute `width` to your sidebar, which in general is fine. But your `<h1>` is declared outside of your sidebar container (which, as already said, has a fixed width). To put your `<h1>` into the center, just specify a `padding-left: 300px;` *(as already mentioned a few times by others in here)* to your `<h1>` or, and that's more responsive for future purposes, wrap your `sidebar` and `<h1>` inside a parental container, so your `sidebar` and `<h1>` will automatically fit into that parent container. While doing so, using `text-align: center;` on your `<h1>` should work without a padding.

Answer (score 2):

You are using wrong HTML, So i will not go any forward.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#81F781">
<div id="sidebar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    </ul>  
</div>
<div id="content">
    <h1> Informational Tech Site</h1>
<div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is most odd question on S.O. CSS as if intermediate developer. and HTML as if first time in coding

Comment: first replace your html with mine. and then code css for it.

Answer (score 1):

Add `padding-left:300px` to `body`
This is something to do with layouts.

Anyhow, as your side bar width is 300px and fixed positioned, you could just add `padding-left:300px` to `body`, so any content added will be aligned into the green place.

Answer (score 1):

As per you code add `margin-left:300px;` to `h1` will make your h1 in proper center.

Because your sidebar is fixed and having `width:300px`.

And why your have `h1` in `head` section.

```css
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0px;
  width: 300px;
  background: #6495ED;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 300px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #6495ED;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: #000000;
  padding: 8px 0 8px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: "Verdana", Geneva, sans-serif;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #27C0FD;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">

<body bgcolor="#81F781">

  <head>
    <h1> Informational Tech Site</h1>

  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="sidebar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </body>
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w4w1uthf/)**

Answer (score 0):

First, your elements isn't sorting well, you have to write the `<h1>` inside the `<body>` tag not in `<head>`

To center the h1 you have to add 300px padding in left, because your 'fixed' positioning sidebar isn't take physical place in body canvas, so, if you're using 'fixed' or 'absolute' positioning it's not taking effect in positioning of other elements.

Answer (score 0):

**Here you go:**

```
.sidebar {
   position: fixed;
   height:100%; 
   left: 0;
   top: 0px;
   width: 25%;
   background:#6495ED; 
   }
   #Content {
     width: 75%;
     float: right;
   }
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k397sy3s/)**

You need another `div` to put `h1` to it then use `percentage` for `width` of both divs, mean new div called `content` and `sidebar`. your issue is `h1` got full width of your page because your `sidebar` has `fixed` position and you need to use `percentage` width to keep them equal. just a `float: right` for `content` and `width: 75%;` and `25% width` for `sidebar` will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use following `css` for `.sldebar` rule:

```
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0px;
  width: 300px;
  background: #6495ED;
  transform: translateX(-50%); 
}
```